# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Maps.safeGet(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Tags: guava, nosuchmethoderror

I am using guava-13.0.jar.
It is included in the classpath.

I am using netbeans Java Free Form Project.

Though I clean-build the project, I am getting the following exception.

```
Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Maps.safeGet(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at com.google.common.collect.StandardTable.get(StandardTable.java:117)
        at com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable.get(HashBasedTable.java:135)
```

Can someone point out how can I fix this error?

Comment: Such problems occurs when you're mixing multiple Guava versions on the classpath. But this would assume there was once a version of `Maps` not containing the method, but in the repo I see the method existing from the time the class was created. Still, I'd check the classpath.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't have an older google-collections jar, or that another of your dependencies does not embed a copy of Guava.